# How to make perfect div for Footer of webpage?

Tags: css, html, xhtml, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the div for my footer (id="Footer") to be 10px from the bottom of my screen. For example, if my page content cannot fill the height of the screen, I want the div to be 10px from the bottom.

If my page content extends further than the bottom of the screen (creating a scroll area), I want the div to still be at the very bottom with a 10px margin from the bottom.

I was using `position: absolute` but that causes my content to fall underneath the footer div if content stretches past page screen height.

**HTML**:
 `<div id="Footer" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>&copy; Copywright  2012 Company. All Rights Reserved</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>`

**CSS**:

```
#Footer  table {
   width: 100%;
   max-width:1250px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;   /* Height of the footer */
   font-weight:bolder;
   background-color: black;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    font-size:20px;
    border: 3px white solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
} 
#Footer  {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #15317E;
    clear: both;
    width: 1250px;
}
```

Comment: What is the containing element of the footer div?

Comment: Absolute positioned element are removed from the html normal flow. this is because your content fall underneath the footer div. i would like to see your content area css to suggest you a fix

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the problem that makes content fall underneath the footer div after adding **position: absolute** and **bottom: 10px** to the **footer** in the **css** code

You should add some css codes in **body**, so it should be like this

```
body{
    position: relative; /* to make footer in the bottom of the body*/
    padding-bottom: 45px;  /*footer heigh + 10px*/
    margin: 0; /*to make footer fill the screen width without scroll*/
}
```

Also you need to set the **footer**'s **height** to a static number, so it will be

```
#Footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #15317E;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, change #Footer to below code:

```
#Footer  {
    clear: both; /*may be omitted*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color: #15317E;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; /* or anything you like */
 }
```

In your CSS, body must have the following:

```
position:relative;
```

bottom: 0; will position your footer to the bottom no matter what.